# Php laravel login and registration notification error

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have registration and authorization forms. They work, except for the error output. For example, if authorization is unsuccessful, it should display the error 'Authorization failed' on the 'number' field. Or, during registration, it should display in the number field 'This user is already registered'. In this case, the redirect works, but_the_errors_themselves are not displayed. That is, the page is simply being updated. What could be the mistake?
registration.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title-block')
    Регистрация
@endsection

@section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <h1 align="center">
            <a href="/"><img src="{{asset('images/logo.jpg')}}" alt="logo" class="home"></a>
            Register
        </h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container" align="center">
        <form name="register" method="POST" action="{{route('user.registration')}}">
            @csrf
            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your surname" name="surname" required>
            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" required><br>

            <input class="text-input-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Enter your number" name="number" required><br>

            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your father`s name" name="fathers_name" required>
            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter parent number" name="parents_number" required><br>

            <input class="text-input-full-width" id="password" name="password" type="password" required placeholder="Enter password"><br>

            <label for="studies"id="RegistrationForm"><b>Choose your studies</b></label><br>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic checkbox toggle button group">
                <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btncheck1" autocomplete="off" name="btnstudies[]" value="Math">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btncheck1">Math</label>

                <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btncheck2" autocomplete="off" name="btnstudies[]" value="Language">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btncheck2">Language</label>

                <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btncheck3" autocomplete="off" name="btnstudies[]" value="Physics">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btncheck3">Physics</label>

    </div>
            <br>
            <label for="classes"id="RegistrationForm"><b>Classes</b></label><br>

            <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group">

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked value="2">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">2nd class</label>

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off" value="3">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2" >3rd class</label>

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off" value="4">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">4th class</label>

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio4" autocomplete="off" value="5">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio4">5th class</label>

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio5" autocomplete="off" value="6">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio5">6th class</label>

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio6" autocomplete="off" value="7">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio6">7th class</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="final">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check-term" id="btncheck4" autocomplete="off" required>
                <label class="check-agree" for="btncheck4">I agree with a <a href="documents/term.txt">Terms</a></label><br>
                <button class="main-button" type="submit" name="sendMe" value="1" required>Register</button><br>
                <br><label class="check-agree" for="btncheck5">If you have already registrated, <a href="/login"> log in</a></label>
            </div>
            <hr>

    </form>
@endsection
```

RegisterController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
//    public function studies(Request $request){
//        dd($request->get('btnstudies'));
//        //you an store it in database now
//    }
    public function save(Request $request){
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }

    $validateFields = $request->validate([

        'number' =>'required',
        'password' => 'required',

    ]);
        if(User::where('number',$request['number'])->exists()){
            return redirect(route('user.registration'))->withErrors([
                'number' => 'Такой пользователь уже зарегистрирован',



            ]);
        }
 $studies = implode(", ",$request['btnstudies'] );
    $user = User::create([

        'password' => $request['password'],
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'surname'=>$request['surname'],
        'number'=>$request['number'],
        'fathers_name'=>$request['fathers_name'],
        'parents_number'=>$request['parents_number'],
        'class' => $request['btnradio'],
        'studies' =>$studies
    ]);

    if($user){
        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(route('user.private'));
    }

        return redirect(route('user.login'))->withErrors([
            'formError' => 'Произошла ошибка при сохранении пользователя'
        ]);
    }
}
```

login.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title-block')
    Log in
@endsection
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <h1 align="center">
            <a href="/"><img src="{{asset('images/logo.jpg')}}" alt="logo" class="home"></a>
            Log in
        </h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container" align="center">
        <form name="sign" method="POST" action="{{route('user.login')}}">
        @csrf


            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your number" name="number">
            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password">

            <button class="main-button" type="submit" name="sendMe" value="1" required>Log in</button><br>
            <br><label class="check-agree" for="btncheck5">Don't have an account? You can <a href="/registration"> register it right now</a></label>
    </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
@endsection
```

LoginController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request){
        $formFields = $request->only('number','password');
        if(Auth::attempt($formFields)){
            return redirect()->intended('/private');
        }
        return redirect(route('user.login'))->withErrors([
           'number' => 'Авторизоваться не удалось'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can validate for unique number field in the validation step

```
$validateFields = $request->validate([
  'number' =>'required|unique:users,number',
  'password' => 'required',
]);
```

for the redirect take a look at the documents https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: I added $ validateFields = $ request-> validate ([
  'number' => 'required | unique: users, number',
  'password' => 'required',
]); But after registering with the number that is already in the database, I get Page expired. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

for displaying a specific error You may use the following code

```
@error('feild')
    <span class="text-danger">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
@enderror
```

just replace 'feild' with the name of the parameter that the error is related to.

Or You could use this code to display all the errors

```
    @if ($errors->any())
       @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <div class="text-danger">
               {{ $error }}
           </div>
       @endforeach 
   @endif
```